# Set firebase firestore security role to show data only if resources field is true

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here is the database structure /collection/document/collection2/document2, in document2 there is a field called visibility and it is set to either public or private. I added the following security rule to show only public records but I am getting insufficient permission error in both cases. even I set all document's visibility to the public.

here is the security rule I tried.

```
match /{collection}/{document} {
  match /{collection2}/{document2} {
    allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public';
    allow write;
  }
  
}
```

Tried another way

```
match /{collection}/{document}/{collection2}/{document2} {
    allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public';
    allow write;
}
```

non of the above worked. I also tried using the pathname instead of a wildcard but still no result. here is the client-side query

```
   fs.collection('collection').doc('document').collection('collection2').doc('document2')
.get()
.then(function(snapshot){
      
}).catch(function() {
   
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that performs the query that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: My initial guess is that your code tries to read all of `collection2`, which isn't allowed. Please read the documentation on [rules not filtering the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters). If that is not the problem, indeed add the code that performs the query to your question as Doug asked.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the client-side query please take a look.

Comment: `{collection}`, `{document2}` etc act as a variable and not the exact values of your database. While querying on the client side, are you sure that **'collection' named collection exists?**

Comment: @frunkad yes the collection name is correct. I added where('visibility', '==','public') in client-side it worked but the app is very dynamic and various rules are applied. adding where query every time in client-side will affect the app stability.

Comment: The where query runs on firebase servers so shouldn't have a performance issue, moreover, it being a security concern it's better to have them in the firestore rules.

Comment: Also using wildcard `{collection}` means it would match every base collection of your database. The issue might be caused by any other query you are making on the client side. Could you provide the error logs or show some parts of your database?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Can you log the error in the code, so that we can see that it indeed is a "permission denied". Also: can you add a screenshot from the Firesture console of the document yuo're trying to read?